# Retrieving titles/ids of lists except libraries?

Tags: list, library

Is there a way to retrieve IDs/Titles of lists on a web without retrieving IDs/Titles of libraries?

In a SPFX webpart you can use

```
return this.context.spHttpClient.get(this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + `/_api/web/lists?$filter=Hidden eq false`, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
  .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
    return response.json();
  });`
```

to retrieve titles of lists, but it also return titles of libraries.

I need titles/IDs of lists for a Picker. 
I currently use PropertyFieldListPicker from @pnp/spfx-property-controls which displays IDs of lists(including libraries).

Comment: You need to add more details to your question. Retrive using what?

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the SPFx part. But using REST api you can get all lists on a web. By using filter on BaseType of list using following URL:

```
siteUrl/_api/web/lists?$filter=BaseType eq 0
```

BaseType = 0 is for Generic List. 
BaseType = 1 is for Document Libraries

You can get the detailed information about BaseType property [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/BaseType-element-site).

Please upvote if this answer helped you in any way.